# How do I underline each order via conditional formatting?

Tags: conditional-formatting, rules

I'm export data from OSAS 7.6 into an Excel Spreadsheet, and I need a rule that will create a bottom border per record(Order No.)I know how to underline each row, but some orders require multiple rows, and I don't want EACH one underlined. HELP!!!!!!!

[http://imgur.com/a/qmqw4](https://imgur.com/a/qmqw4)

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: You also need to tell us which program you're using. At the moment your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Try this, referring to your screenshot looks like you have your data arranged from A13 onwards in a Pivot Table. Select range of cells starting A13 where your table is and apply the following conditional formatting formula rule =ISBLANK($A13)=FALSE  and select the desired underline format. This should only underline those rows where there is data (your order number) in column A cells.

Comment: Ok...I did as you said, it DID create underlining, both it has spilt some of the records. So I'm almost there. I need the underlining at the bottom of each record.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by '..it has split some of the records'. May be a screenshot of what you have achieved so far could help.

Comment: order No. 00046092 uses 1 line because it contains 1 item. 00046095 uses 2 line because it has 2 items, etc. etc. Right now only the line adjacent to the actual Order No. is underlined. As in the attached pic, I would like to have each entire order bordered.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/SYlYC

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for assisting me with this project.

Comment: For the same formula which border did you select? Underline or Top one? Try selecting top border. Now it will underline the previous row i.e. top border for the current row. This will only create horizontal border, not a rectangular box though.

Comment: I need the rectangular box.

Comment: It just crossed my mind, if I had a formula that would make each record a different color, it would work the same, just trying to seperate the records.

Comment: That did it!!!! The Top border!!!!! THANKS A MILLION!!!!!

Comment: All right. I just posted a detailed answer based on my understanding. It involves one manual step to outline the entire table in case you need  a full rectangular box per order.

Comment: How do i sort the entire table based on the Order Date?

Comment: normal sorting methods aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding I giving an indicative solution whereby you can get a rectangular box per order. Let's start with raw table without any borders as in below snapshot.

[image]

First select the entire table and manually put an outline border once without any conditional formatting. This becomes as below.
[image]

Now select the entire table and put a following Formula Rule as Conditional Format and select top line as format.

```
=ISBLANK($A1)=FALSE
```

[image]

Now you have a full rectangular border per Order Id box.

[image]